# What are pros/cons of global fields in a module vs static class variables in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

What are the pro/cons to put a field in the exports vs. making it a static class variable?

I end up mixing it up as seen below (which is the baddest way for sure).

```
export const stringItemsCollection = 'stringItems';

export const loadingString = '...';

export default class DatabaseStringItem {
  static readonly encryptionKey: string;
}
```

Comment: See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#needless-namespacing

Comment: @Aaron: So you mean a static var in a class  is comparable to Needless Namespacing?

Comment: Yes, I would say that classes with static members is comparable to "needless namespacing" in the docs. You can still do it if you want, of course. I will say that in my experiences namespaces and static classes have a bit better IDE support (auto-import, auto-suggestions) than module files. But it's not really idiomatic JavaScript at this point.

Comment: If you want to work in an object oriented manner (which classes can be used for), then both are bad. Variables should be properties of class instances.

Comment: @Kokodoko umm. I dont think so. How would you declare global class variables then if not static?

Comment: Global variables are bad practice if you want to adhere to strict OOP standards - where variables always reflect the state of a class instance. You can use a Singleton pattern, or a library such as Redux, to have a globally available state.

Comment: Of course no one will stop you if you mix different programming styles, except the OOP police. Just be aware that objects become harder to test if they depend on all kinds of global variables.

Comment: @Kokodoko that is incorrect. There are cases where you need one variable shared across all instances. Sure you can implement that purely as OO with a separate class that has one instance shared with all instances of the other class, but that's extra work.